# where liferay site will store in which table details will fetch?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7, liferay-aui

if we create site,organisation where it will store.i mean in which default table it will store.`Programmatically create organization site from site template

```
Create organization site

Organization organization = OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.addOrganization(creatorUserId, 0, name, createSite);

Fetch site templates

List<LayoutSetPrototype> layoutSetPrototypes =
LayoutSetPrototypeLocalServiceUtil.getLayoutSetPrototypes(organization.getCompanyId());
LayoutSetPrototype customSiteTemplate = null;
// find CustomSiteTemplate
for (LayoutSetPrototype layoutSetPrototype : layoutSetPrototypes) {
    if (layoutSetPrototype.getName(Locale.ENGLISH)) .equalsIgnoreCase("CustomSiteTemplate") {
        customSiteTemplate = layoutSetPrototype;
        break;
    }
}

Assign site template(CustomSiteTemplate) pages to organization site.

if (customerSiteTemplate != null && organization != null) {
    LayoutSet layoutSet =
    LayoutSetLocalServiceUtil.getLayoutSet(organization.getGroupId(), true);
    layoutSet.setLayoutSetPrototypeLinkEnabled(true);
    layoutSet.setLayoutSetPrototypeUuid(customerSiteTemplate.getUuid());
    LayoutSetLocalServiceUtil.updateLayoutSet(layoutSet);
    // Merge Site template pages to organization site.
    SitesUtil.mergeLayoutSetPrototypeLayouts(organization.getGroup(),layoutSet);
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

A non-answer to this question (albeit it's the only correct answer as well) is: You *do not want* to look at the database. *Period*. It's Liferay's database, and if you make any changes to it, you'll most likely wreak havoc - been there, done that.

A lengthy and more complete argument [can be found here](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/67061448), trust me: We've seen quite a lot of problems caused by people who assumed they knew Liferay's database. Save yourself this hassle and resist from checking it out.

Comment: Anyhow it will store somewhere.. without storing the site value.. how we will fetch the details.. anyhow thanks bro.

Comment: Sure it will, but answering this question to the letter will only help yourself and others to get into a lot of trouble. And you don't give any indicator that you might have a good reason for this question other than curiosity (which is fine, I'll just not he'll you satisfy your curiosity. Seen to many things going wrong with this)