# Liferay 6.2 - No UserNotificationEvent exists with the primary key?

Tags: notifications, liferay-6

I'm facing an issue regarding Notifications on my portal (Liferay 6.2).

When I had the idea to clean old (& useless) notifications from the DB table USERNOTIFICATIONEVENT my notification portlet crashes.

Every time I open the notifications I get the following error:

`Caused by: com.liferay.portal.NoSuchUserNotificationEventException: No UserNotificationEvent exists with the primary key 115765`

Although my table is empty, and I login in with a user the notifications show to be 20 (for example) and when I click on them I get the error. Creating a new notification with java code, the table updates and inserts the new notifications, so after that the notifications show to be 21.

How is that possible to see 21 notifications when in USERNOTIFICATIONEVENT exists only 1 record?

Answer (score 0):

How is it possible? It's because you manipulated the database without fully understanding it, a common recipe for disaster. Check [where liferay site will store in which table details will fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912516) for an argument to not bother. If you do anything on the database, do it through the API, never through database manipulation. Also check the link contained in that answer.

There are typically additional data structures, metadata for example for permission checks or the full text index that you'd need to update as well. And that's not a complete list

Restore your backup is the safest way to recover, because even if you get it to work now otherwise, the upgrade routines to the next version might find unexpected data. And then it's too late